# Pull text from within span class to FacetWP Proximity Input text field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facetwp

I'm able to copy the text from within the span class to the input field automatically on page load but I am unable to get FacetWP to respond and update the results even when using `FWP.refresh()`

https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/javascript/facetwp-refresh/

Facet name - `proximity`

Span class - `local-addrress-name`

Input class - `facetwp-location`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.local-address-name');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
document.querySelector('.facetwp-location').value =last.innerHTML;
  setTimeout(function() {  
FWP.refresh(); // Change a facet value
         console.log( "ready!" );
  }, 2000);

    
});
```

```html
<span class="local-address-name">Brunswick, GA, USA</span>

<input type="text" class="facetwp-location" value="" placeholder="Enter Zip or Address" id="facetwp-location" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FacetWP relies on hidden lat/lng fields that do the heavy lifting, was then just syncing everything up. This is such a simple way to achieve related products by lat/lng location proximity on each single product page. Cheers!

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.local-address-name');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
document.querySelector('.facetwp-location').value =last.innerHTML;
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.local-lat-val');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
document.querySelector('.facetwp-lat').value =last.innerHTML;
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.local-lng-val');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
document.querySelector('.facetwp-lng').value =last.innerHTML;
FWP.refresh('');
});
```